# How can I pass a parameter from BAT-file to an encoded powershell-script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to execute an encoded powershell-script from a Windows-batch and pass a parameter to it.

Let's take for example the following script:

```
param (
    $foo
)
Write-Host("Hello World!" + $foo)
```

When encoding it to base64, the result is:

```
cABhAHIAYQBtACAAKAANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAkAGYAbwBvAA0ACgApAA0ACgBXAHIAaQB0AGUALQBIAG8AcwB0ACgAIgBIAGUAbABsAG8AIABXAG8AcgBsAGQAIQAiACAAKwAgACQAZgBvAG8AKQA=
```

I do then create a batch-skript:

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand "cABhAHIAYQBtACAAKAANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAkAGYAbwBvAA0ACgApAA0ACgBXAHIAaQB0AGUALQBIAG8AcwB0ACgAIgBIAGUAbABsAG8AIABXAG8AcgBsAGQAIQAiACAAKwAgACQAZgBvAG8AKQA="
```

How can I pass a parameter to the powershell to make it output a value for $foo after "Hello World!"?

Due to the circumstances, I cannot create another script-file or anything similar. The whole process should be contained in the BAT-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell does not support passing arguments to a script that is encrypted natively.

You can however set variables in the .bat file, then in your script retrieve them.

For example:

```
$command = 'write-host $env:test '
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

$encodedCommand
```

The encoded command is now: `dwByAGkAdABlAC0AaABvAHMAdAAgACQAZQBuAHYAOgB0AGUAcwB0ACAA`

In your batch file, you can now have:

```
@echo off
set test=MyVar
Powershell -encodedcommand dwByAGkAdABlAC0AaABvAHMAdAAgACQAZQBuAHYAOgB0AGUAcwB0ACAA
```

When you run the batchfile, it will now print `MyVar`.